# How to Control Programmatically Generated TextViews

Tags: android, textview, generated

I appreciate your help if someone can provide me with a solution. I have two question:

1- I have a button that generates Params and TextView every time I click it. I set variables to textview "textnew" and param "lptxt". However, I only can control the last generated textview, typeface, font size, removing..etc. Is there a method to set automatic id and I can recall it in other methods? I tried isSelected, isTouched, hasFocus, and others but nothing worked.

2- How can I set my TextView back to the way it was after setting borders? Let's say I have set borders to the TextView of 10dp radius and a red color. but when touching the TextView, the borders change to 1dp radius as stated in drawable/corners.

Thank you

Here's my code

```
RelativeLayout rel0 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel0);
```

OnClick:

```
textnew = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    lptxt = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            lptxt.addRule((RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));
                            lptxt.addRule((RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL));
                            lptxt.addRule((RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT));
                            textnew.setLayoutParams(lptxt);
                            rel0.addView(textnew);
                            rel0.bringChildToFront(textnew);
                            rel0.bringToFront();
                            textnew.setText(edittextdialog.getText().toString());
```

OnTouch:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        textnew.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borders);
                        textnew.isSelected();

                        break;
                    }
```

**BTW I'm working on API 11**

Thank you in advance,

Comment: you can set Id in textview https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()

Comment: The textview is programmatically created. Means I want the button to create textviews but if I set id, it'll be for one. Yes I can recall it but it'll be only one.

Comment: That solution is for API 17. I'm on 11. thanx though

Comment: you do not need set id, just use `textnew` in other methods. You can put the TextView objects into a List

Comment: @tesla1984 I tried so. but I only can control the last generated textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this problem:

I inflated a view on ACTION_UP, where I can change text size, color, font, and even delete it. The changes happen directly on the selected textview with problem.

Thanx guys for contributing.

Here's my code:

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

    LayoutInflater lifirst = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View lifirstpv = lifirst.inflate(R.layout.infirst, null);
    final TextView editfirst = TextView)lifirstpv.findViewById(R.id.editfirst);
    final TextView deletefirst = (TextView)lifirstpv.findViewById(R.id.deletefirst);

    pop = new PopupWindow(
lifirstpv,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    pop.setOutsideTouchable(true); pop.setTouchable(true);
    deletefirst.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    rel0.removeView(teext);
    pop.dismiss();
    return true;
                   }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `setTag` on your `TextView` and use `findViewWithTag` to get the View you need.
2. reset everything back on `ACTION_UP`

Answer (score 0):

For example, you generate 5 `TextView`

```
List<TextView> list = new ArrayList<TextView>();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
     TextView textView = generateTextView();
     list.add(textView);
     rel0.addView(textView);
}
```

the method generate TextView

```
public TextView generateTextView(){
    TextView textnew = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    ...
    return textnew;
}
```

then you can control the textviews in the list

the textview is using relativelayoutparams ,if you use the same `lptxt` layoutparams. the textviews will be the same position,you can only see the last one

Comment: That's a good thought but I don't want to use a list and I don't want to limit the user of textviews. Also, I'm generating layoutparams with the textviews. So, each textview has its own layoutparam. I can see and move each one, that as far as it gets. But I can only delete or typeface the last one. From my coding, am I missing something?

Comment: @Badee can you show more code about 'delete or typeface'?

Comment: to remove I use rel0.removeView(textnew);

Comment: for typface I'm using Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "aaa.ttf");
                    textnew.setTypeface(tf);

Comment: can you show full code in the question?there is nothing wrong with the code you post